# SharePoint if statements for registering css

Tags: user-controls, browser-compatibility, cssregistration

In regular old HTMl we are allowed to do the following to use a css file depending on browser versions:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-styles/css/cssfilename.css">
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-styles/css/cssfilename.css">
<![endif]-->
```

in a sharepoint user control we can add the files like so:

```
 <SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/_layouts/solutionfolder/filename.css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>
```

How can I determine which version of the style sheet to load based on browser version? Or do I register them all then later determine which to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ConditionalExpression property to specify your conditional browser version.

For ex.

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration name="/_layouts/solutionfolder/filename.css" After="corev4.css" ConditionalExpression="lt IE 7" runat="server" />
```